# Conflicts when find and "replace" a method dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, metaprogramming

I have a class consisting of a "list" of static methods, `A`. I want to change its behavior with a class-decorator, `Meta`, which acts on a specific static method, in this example `content`, by performing the method `m`.

My original attempt, `CASE=2`, didn't work as expected, so I started I case study. I introduced a new class `B`, which has slightly different implementation of an other method, `info` but raised a funny error, and a new class `C` just without the method, `info`.

- case 2: the *greedy* case

`d[i] = classmethod(lambda cls, *args: mcs.m( getattr(target_cls, i)(*args)) )` **it doesn't work properly**, maybe too many nested dynamic expressions?

- case 1: it essentially case 2 but the expression is divided in two lines, and **it works**

```
   o = getattr(target_cls, i)
   d[i] = classmethod(lambda cls, *args: mcs.m(o(*args)))
```

Here the code

```
class Meta:

    def __new__(mcs, target_cls):
        if CASE == 1:
            print('case 1')
            d = {}
            for i in dir(target_cls):
                 if i == 'content':
                    o = getattr(target_cls, i)
                    d[i] = classmethod(lambda cls, *args: mcs.m(o(*args)))

        if CASE == 2:
            print('case 2')
            d = {}
            for i in dir(target_cls):
                 if i == 'content':
                    d[i] = classmethod(lambda cls, *args: mcs.m( getattr(target_cls, i)(*args)) )

        return type('AAA', (target_cls,), d)

    @classmethod
    def m(mcs, p):

        return '--> ', p


class A:

    @staticmethod
    def content(response):
        return 'static_method', response
    @staticmethod
    def info(response):
        return response


class B:

    @staticmethod
    def content(response):
        return 'static_method', response
    @staticmethod
    def info(response):
        response.sort()
        return response

class C:

    @staticmethod
    def content(response):
        return 'static_method', response

# call the "content" class-method of each class for all different cases
for cls in (A, B, C):
    print(cls.__name__)
    for case in range(1,3):
        CASE = case
        R = Meta(cls)
        try:
            print(R.content('ppp'))
        except Exception as e: print(e)
    
    print()
```

Output

```
A
case 1
('--> ', ('static_method', 'ppp'))
case 2
('--> ', 'ppp')        # no decoration

B
case 1
('--> ', ('static_method', 'ppp'))
case 2
'str' object has no attribute 'sort'  # <- complained about the other method

C              # <- this is ok BUT I removed the other method!
case 1
('--> ', ('static_method', 'ppp'))
case 2
('--> ', ('static_method', 'ppp'))  # <- here the decoration took place
```

The **question** is why case 2 doesn't work, if it is a limitation of the language then of what kind?

Extra question: how to explain the error of class `B` case 2

Comment: working with Python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the issue is caused by the loop and the origin is the fact that each statement *has not its own scope* (in the loop). By passing `i` as a key parameter of the `lambda` fixed the problem.

```
class Meta:

    def __new__(mcs, target_cls):
        d = {}
        for i in dir(target_cls):
             if i == 'content':
                d[i] = classmethod(lambda cls, *args, m_name=i: mcs.m( getattr(target_cls, m_name)(*args)) )
    
        return type('AAA', (target_cls,), d)

    @classmethod
    def m(mcs, p):
        return '--> ', p

class A:

    @staticmethod
    def content(response):
        return 'static_method', response

    @staticmethod
    def info(response):
        return response

print(A.content)
print(Meta(A).content)
print(Meta(A).content('a'))
print(Meta(A).info)
```

Output

```
<function A.content at 0x7f04500740d0> # original static method
<bound method Meta.__new__.<locals>.<lambda> of <class '__main__.AAA'>> # class method
('--> ', ('static_method', 'a'))
<function A.info at 0x7f0450074040>
```